# "Internal Server Error" on QBO Api Update call

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

When I send an update request to the QBO V2 api, I get back an 'internal server error' response. These requests used to work; I even have an unchanged unit test from before specifically for this request that no longer works.

All of my other request types seem to still be working. Normally QBO gives pretty decent error messages if it's something I messed up with the request.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue recently, or have any ideas on what I could be doing that wouldn't result in a normal error message?

Here's a copy of one of the requests:

```
POST /resource/customer/v2/682571780/1?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=*token*&oauth_nonce=*nonce*&oauth_timestamp=1372345998&oauth_signature=*signature*&oauth_consumer_key=*key*&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1 HTTP/1.1
Host: qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com
Content-Length: 1368
content-type: application/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.5.0-17-generic

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII' standalone='yes'?>
<Customer xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Id idDomain="QBO">1</Id>
  <SyncToken>49</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2013-04-10T14:07:41-07:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-25T09:40:40-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <Name>Test A. User</Name>
  <Address>
    <Line1>123 Test Drive</Line1>
    <City>Smallville</City>
    <Country>United States of America</Country>
    <CountrySubDivisionCode>WY</CountrySubDivisionCode>
    <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    <GeoCode>LAT=42.8142432,LNG=-73.9395687</GeoCode>
    <Tag>Billing</Tag>
  </Address>
  <Phone>
    <DeviceType>Primary</DeviceType>
    <FreeFormNumber>(123) 456-7890</FreeFormNumber>
  </Phone>
  <WebSite/>
  <Email>
    <Address>test-user@mailinator.com</Address>
  </Email>
  <GivenName>Test</GivenName>
  <MiddleName>A</MiddleName>
  <FamilyName>User</FamilyName>
  <DBAName>Emerging Threats</DBAName>
  <CustomField>
    <DefinitionId>Preferred Delivery Method</DefinitionId>
    <Value>PRINT</Value>
  </CustomField>
  <CustomField>
    <DefinitionId>Resale Number</DefinitionId>
  </CustomField>
  <CustomField>
    <DefinitionId>Bill With Parent</DefinitionId>
    <Value>false</Value>
  </CustomField>
  <ShowAs>Test User</ShowAs>
  <OpenBalance>
    <Amount>20.00</Amount>
  </OpenBalance>
</Customer>
```

Comment: When did it start happening and is it still going on?

Comment: Since I don't have as many use cases that involve updating customers, I only noticed it in the past few days. I just did another test with updating the status of an Estimate, and that still works. So my basic update request code should be fine, it's just something that's wrong with trying to update a customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try the following XML in ApiExplorer. It worked fine for me.
ApiExplorer - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO

Please change the Id and Synctoken, Name etc with correct test data.

PN - Looks like customeFields in the post body are not supported while updating QBO Customer. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/customer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <Id>4</Id>
    <SyncToken>6</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-04-10T14:07:41-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-25T09:40:40-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <TypeOf>Person</TypeOf>
    <Name>John Doe NEW 2</Name>
    <Address>
        <Line1>123 Test Drive</Line1>
        <City>Smallville</City>
        <Country>United States of America</Country>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>WY</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
        <GeoCode>LAT=42.8142432,LNG=-73.9395687</GeoCode>
        <Tag>Billing</Tag>
    </Address>
    <Phone>
        <DeviceType>Primary</DeviceType>
        <FreeFormNumber>(123) 456-7890</FreeFormNumber>
    </Phone>
    <WebSite/>
    <Email>
        <Address>test-user@mailinator.com</Address>
    </Email>
    <GivenName>Test</GivenName>
    <MiddleName>A</MiddleName>
    <FamilyName>User</FamilyName>
    <DBAName>Emerging Threats</DBAName>
    <ShowAs>Test User</ShowAs>
    <OpenBalance>
        <Amount>20.00</Amount>
    </OpenBalance>
</Customer>
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what the problem was. Now I just remove the CustomFields before posting, and the update functions correctly. The annoying part about this is that I never actually added those custom fields myself; they were part of the response from the customer 'GET' request.